# Install pytorch fail on win10 external GPU

Tags: python, conda, pytorch

I can not import pytorch on my gpu conda env:

```
C:\Users\Jeffy\Desktop
$ python
Python 3.7.2 (default, Feb 11 2019, 14:11:50) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

- I have two conda env, one is **gpu** with external gpu GTX1050, one is **base**.
- On my **base** env, I have installed pytorch-cpu version and it works well.
- However, I cannot install pytorch gpu version on my **gpu** env.
- on my **gpu** env, I have the following packages installed (including cudnn, intel-openmp, cmake and so on):

```
$ conda list
 packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\gpu:

 Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
astor                     0.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                         mkl
ca-certificates           2019.1.23                     0
certifi                   2018.11.29               py37_0
cffi                      1.11.5           py37h74b6da3_1
cmake                     3.12.2               he025d50_0
cudatoolkit               10.0.130                      0
cudnn                     7.3.1                cuda10.0_0
freetype                  2.9.1                ha9979f8_1
gast                      0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.18.0                   pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      2.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
intel-openmp              2019.0                   pypi_0    pypi
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
keras-applications        1.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
libpng                    1.6.36               h2a8f88b_0
libtiff                   4.0.10               hb898794_2
markdown                  3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2019.1                      144
mkl-include               2019.1                      144
mkl_fft                   1.0.10           py37h14836fe_0
mkl_random                1.0.2            py37h343c172_0
mock                      2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ninja                     1.8.2.post2              pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.15.4           py37h19fb1c0_0
numpy-base                1.15.4           py37hc3f5095_0
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0
openssl                   1.1.1a               he774522_0
pbr                       5.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    5.4.1            py37hdc69c19_0
pip                       19.0.1                   py37_0
protobuf                  3.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0
python                    3.7.2                h8c8aaf0_2
pytorch                   1.0.1           py3.7_cuda100_cudnn7_1    pytorch
pyyaml                    3.13             py37hfa6e2cd_0
setuptools                40.7.3                   py37_0
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0
sqlite                    3.26.0               he774522_0
tensorboard               1.12.2                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      1.13.0rc0                pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-gpu            1.13.0rc1                pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.8                hfa6e2cd_0
torchvision               0.2.1                      py_2    pytorch
typing                    3.6.4                    py37_0
vc                        14.1                 h21ff451_1    peterjc123
vs2015_runtime            14.15.26706          h3a45250_0
vs2017_runtime            15.4.27004.2010               1    peterjc123
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.32.3                   py37_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
xz                        5.2.4                h2fa13f4_4
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_3
zstd                      1.3.7                h508b16e_0
```

Comment: See https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/4518#issuecomment-462631470

Answer (score 0):

Expecting Cuda and Cudnn has been already installed and Updated the Environment variable list.

Try installing pytorch using the command

conda install pytorch -c pytorch

or

conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.0.130 -c pytorch